# Python String Formatting, difference in code

Tags: python, string, formatting

Hi I am trying to understand how the string formatting works with float:

I have tried

```
>>> print("%s %s %s %s %-9.10f"%("this","is","monday","morning",56.3648))
```

it gives output of

```
this is monday morning 56.3648000000
```

however this,

```
>>> print("%s %s %s %s %10f"%("this","is","monday","morning",56.3648))
```

gives output of

```
this is monday morning  56.364800
```

what is causing the difference?

Answer (score 2):

[The way the pattern strings are parsed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting). `%9.10f` sets the (minimum) field width to 9 and the precision to 10, while `%10f` only sets the *width* to 10. I think you meant to write `%.10f` instead:

```
In [4]: '%10f' % 56.3648 # width
Out[4]: ' 56.364800'

In [5]: '%.10f' % 56.3648 # precision
Out[5]: '56.3648000000'
```

Also, consider using [the newer `str.format` formatting style](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html?highlight=formatting#format-specification-mini-language). Your first example would turn into

```
In [6]: '{} {} {} {} {:<9.10f}'.format('this', 'is', 'monday', 'morning', 56.3648)
Out[6]: 'this is monday morning 56.3648000000'
```